# How can I create enum type with dataType (String, Integer, boolean) in Android Studio using Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, enums

I have an object with String values. And in one parameter of this object I store dataType of the other parameter. I was wondering if there is a way to create enum type like this:

```
public enum KeyType {
    String,
    Integer,
    boolean
}
```

I have an application with all settings of the different apps installed on smartphone. And I have a service which stores the whole data. I sent objects to this service from other apps. And I am trying to avoid creating three types of this object because only difference will be this one property type. But I assume this is the only way to do it.

Comment: Include object you mentioned. And tell us why would you like to do that. What is the reason?

Comment: I am not sure what you *really* want to achieve. Information about type of value can be accessed by `value.getClass()` method (assuming `value` is not primitive, since in such case we would already know its type). So why do you need second field for it? Could you clarify your question with example showing how you intend to use such code and for what purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `Class` object in your enum and add the type like this

```
public enum KeyType {
    String(String.class), Integer(Integer.class), Boolean(Boolean.class);

    KeyType(Class _class){mClass = _class;}

    private Class mClass;

    public Class getClassType(){return mClass;}
}
```

and you can use it like

```
KeyType k = KeyType.String;
Class class = k.getClassType();
boolean type = k.getClassType() instanceof String; // true
```